# rendering controls in asp says i need to have a form tag with runat=server, but code doesnt see front end to notice it

Tags: asp.net, controls

I have a Control that is populated with a series of controls.  What i was wanting to do is get the string output.  I tried an example that i was working on, but it seems that since some of the controls are input textboxes that there are issues.  It is telling me that it needs a form with runat="server" set.  My conclusion is that it isnt reading the markup of sorts.

Is there a way to get around it?  I was thinking to wrap the data backend with a form...

so instead of root -> (control1, control2), it would be somethiing like root -> form -> (control1, control2).

The attemps i have been doing:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
HtmlTextWritertw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
root.RenderControl(tw);
```

the error occurs at the root.

In the markup i tried to do stuff like:

```
<form runat=server><asp:pladeholder id="root" /></form>
```

but that didnt work at all.

I have yet to try the root->form->(1,2) but going to attempt it now. **Edit:** I did this attempt, and it no longer caused the one HTMLException, but now an invalid Operation Exception:  **RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();**

I also tried overriding VeriftRenderingInServerForm(Control control){} but that wasnt working either, but maybe i was doing this part wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this code - based on `Controls property` of Place Holder

```
var controlsFlow = new StringBuilder() ;
foreach(var control in yourPlaceHolder.Controls)
{
  controlsFlow.Append(control.Id);
}
```

Nota : Add runat="server" to your PlacHolder

Comment: For some reason, the placeholder is defined serverside, it isnt on the markup

Comment: would that work anyways, I mean, would we need recursion?  I dunno how deep the controls go

Comment: if you have just one level, you don't need , but you can control your level hen you create your control

Comment: Your code does not work at the control.Id because it doesnt understand what var is.   It seems to work if you change it to:    foreach(Control control in placeHolder.Controls){controlsFlow.Appen(control.ID);}

Comment: Doing this with your placeholder works.  Seems like there is still some sort of issue when it comes to input type="text" with the form stuff

Comment: why are you storing the ID of the things in the placeholder and not the data associated with the id?

Comment: you can store the control in your place holder, if you want just store id you don't need placeholder , you need just collection

Comment: ahh, so passing in the ID is equivalent to passing the control into the placeholder?  alright.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to output ASP.net controls, and these require the runat="server" controls because they are not legitimate HTML controls.

If you don't want to access them in the code behind, then you can use regular HTML tags instead. E.g

Comment: Yea, i build the stuff serverside and just trying to putput it to the screen to manipulate.  For some reason it isnt quite working

Comment: my goal is to render the asp.net controls.  Im not trying to straight up view them.